# Using any web language, how do I keep an iframe in my page?

Tags: html, iframe

Okay, so I'm trying to iFrame a webpage. I don't know why, but it won't stay in my page (it pops out and goes to the main page). The code I'm using is:

```
<iframe>http://mywebsite.com</iframe>
```

How do I keep it in my site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `src` property.

```
<iframe src="http://mywebsite.com"></iframe>
```

HTML/text content placed inside the tags of an iframe is treated as "fallback" content that only shows up if the browser doesn't support iframes.  See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/iframe) for full details.

```
<iframe src="http://mywebsite.com">
    This sentence only shows up if the browser doesn't support iframes!
</iframe>
```

Thus, you were creating an iframe that didn't point to any page with its `src` property (so it remained blank), and had the text "`http://mywebsite.com`" as fallback text to appear in browsers that don't support iframes.

**EDIT:**

If you don't control the site, it's possible that the framed site has some logic that says something like:

```
// if we are not the highest frame, someone is try to frame this site
if(window.parent != window)
    // redirect the framing parent site to our site
    window.parent.location.href = 'http://iframedsite.com';
```

This logic detects if the site is being embedded by someone else (e.g., your own site) and redirects the parent frame. You can confirm whether this is the problem by simply framing IANA's website, `https://www.iana.org/` (or just `http://www.example.com`), which plays nicely when it is framed and doesn't do parent-frame redirects.

Comment: What do you mean by "popped out"?  It opened in a new window?  Or the entire page redirected to the source of the iframe?

Comment: No, but instead of being in an iFrame, it goes to the main window. So instead of being http://mywebsite.com, it's http://iFramedWebsite.com

Comment: Now I'm quite confused.  I assumed you wanted to embed `mywebsite.com` inside another page, because you were putting it inside the `<iframe>` tags.  But you actually wanted to nest a different page inside of `mywebsite.com`, and that page you want to nest is on `iFramedWebsite.com`. Is that correct?

Comment: Okay, so let's say my site is mainsite.com. I have a website named iframedsite.com that I want to iframe. When I go to mainsite.com, I briefly see iframedsite.com in the iframe, then see nothing but iframedsite.com, and the URL in my address bar is iframedsite.com

Comment: Ah, I think I know the problem.  Do you control the framed site?  If not, it's possible that the framed site has some logic that says "if `window.parent != window` (i.e., someone is try to frame this site), then set `window.parent.location = 'http://iframedsite.com'`".  The framed site detects if is being embedded and redirects the page parent.  You can confirm if this is happening by simply framing IANA's website, `http://www.example.com`, which plays nicely and doesn't do anything sneaky.

Comment: I don't control it, it's a website such as stackoverflow or google.

Comment: (Edited my above comment with a suggestion to use `example.com` as a test, and added it as an edit to my answer.)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<iframe src="http://mywebsite.com"></iframe>
```